# Backbone best way to filter models by rating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to add an improvement to a currenct filter of mine which takes a collection and filters it by rating (1/2/3/4/5).

At the moment it can only filter by one of these (1/2/3/4/5) numbers but I would like to filter using all of them or part of them together. sorting doesn't matter.

```
 filter_by_rating: function(rating) {
    var filtered;
    if (!!rating && rating !== '') {
      filtered = this.filter(function(model) {
          return model.get("rating") >= parseInt(rating) && model.get("rating") <= parseInt(rating) + 0.5;
      });
      return new Collection(filtered);
    } else {

    }
 return this;
 }
```

If in the current function it accepts only one number , I would like to pass a string of numbers , for example: "3,4,5" and it should filter and bring only the models with the rating of 3 4 and 5

Also, if I have in the array the numbers ["3","4","5"] I would it to filter also "3.5", "4.5"

Comment: You should use underscore (or lo-dash) to do this sort of thing. There is a _groupBy function that may give you something close to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexOf to check if the rating is in your array.

```
filter_by_rating: function(rating){
  if(!Array.isArray(rating)) {
     rating = [rating];
  }

  return new Collection(this.filter(function(model){
    return rating.indexOf(Math.floor(model.get('rating'))) !== -1;
  }));
}
```

Comment: Please notice that if there is rating 3 in the array I would like to filter 3 and 3.5, how to do that ?

Comment: Thanks.  Be aware that you will need polyfills for isArray and indexOf if you are supporting older versions of IE (8 and lower).  They are included in underscore, I used the native methods for clarity.